# how to increase log message size to more than 8K in syslog-ng

Tags: syslog-ng

Syslog-ng seems to only allow up to 8192 bytes of log_msg_size and after which it splits up the log message into multiple log messages. Setting this up in the global options or on the source option to use more than 8192 does not seem to work. I was wondering if there are other options that I need to put in order that very long logs aren't split up. I realize this might be a very rare case on the need for long log messages, but the application logging was designed poorly and we need this functionality currently while the logging is being fixed.

In looking at the source code, it seems that the log_msg_size is stored as a gint type, which in my recollection allows me to store up to +32787 right?

If the max I could put is 8192, then I guess I'll have to come up with something else to process the split logs, otherwise any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use log_msg_size, syslog-ng will use the default 8192.  As far as I've seen, you can increase this using log_msg_size (16384), or whatever value you'd like.  As long as there is no g_maxint set in the code, that is.